# How do I authenticate to the GoDaddy API using C#?

Tags: c#, httpclient, godaddy-api

I have setup an account on GoDaddy and have my developer keys for accessing the API.  Using Fiddler I am able to construct a request that returns results.  However, using the following code from a Console application fails with "Unauthorized".  I'm using the same address and keys in both places.

What am I missing?

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "sso-key VUjHMntw_UyosKRMGaLXE4e3E1h29Xx:DSqM2jiJcRyXvSbLehjYUZ");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?domain=google.com");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

NOTE:  The authorization key and secret have been modified.

The following is what I do in Fiddler that works:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you're sending the auth header as:

```
Authorization: Authorization sso-key VUjHMntw_UyosKRMGaLXE4e3E1h29Xx:DSqM2jiJcRyXvSbLehjYUZ
```

Try this instead:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("sso-key", "VUjHMntw_UyosKRMGaLXE4e3E1h29Xx:DSqM2jiJcRyXvSbLehjYUZ");
```

The `Authorization:` prefix is assigned for you by the method call.

Comment: Thank you!! Also this king of thing doen't work too: 
new AuthenticationHeaderValue($"sso-key {key}:{secret}");

Answer (score 1):

That particular call does not require authentication.  This should work for you.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestDomain().Wait();
    }

    public static async Task<string> TestDomain()
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "sso-key VUjHMntw_UyosKRMGaLXE4e3E1h29Xx:DSqM2jiJcRyXvSbLehjYUZ");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?domain=google.com");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result);

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);

                return response.ReasonPhrase;

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That is correct.  I should have used a different api call to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

'
' Visual Basic
' Console app
' Sign-up for GoDaddy (this only seems to work with PRODUCTION keys, secret and URL
'
' Example use
'  You want to host a domain name at your home (e.g. ISP = Cox Cable) but you have a dynamic IP address, not static
'  Call this routine about once a minute (GoDaddy has a 60 per hour limit) and it will change the A Record at GoDaddy to point to the new IP at your home
'

Module Module1

```
Const DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS As String = "0.0.0.0"
Const GODADDYKEY_AND_SECRET As String = "GoDaddyKeyGoesHere:GoDaddySecretGoesHere"  'key:secret  Get this from GoDaddy API.  Use Production (not test)
Public objGoDaddyResult As Object = Nothing

Public vbWhack As String = "\"

Sub Main()
    Dim sCurrentCoxIPAddress As String
    Dim sCurrentARecordIPAddress As String

    sCurrentCoxIPAddress = GetExternalIPMain()          ' Calls up to three "services" to get you public-facing IP address

    If sCurrentCoxIPAddress <> DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS Then
        Console.WriteLine(sCurrentCoxIPAddress)
        ' Call GoDaddy API to get what the current A Record is set to
        GetGoDaddyARecord().Wait()
        sCurrentARecordIPAddress = ghExtract(Trim(objGoDaddyResult.ToString), ghEscape("\034Data\034:\034"), ghEscape("\034,\034name\034"))
        Console.WriteLine(sCurrentARecordIPAddress)

        If sCurrentCoxIPAddress = sCurrentARecordIPAddress Then
            Console.WriteLine("IP Addresses match, nothing to do")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Cox dynamically changed my IP.  Changed A Record at GoDaddy")
            'Call GoDaddy API to Change A Record.
            PutGoDaddyARecord(sCurrentCoxIPAddress).Wait()
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(objGoDaddyResult)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Could not find IP address after looking at three Websites")
    End If

    Console.ReadKey()
    End

End Sub

Private Async Function GetGoDaddyARecord() As Task(Of String)
    Dim MyWebClient = New Net.Http.HttpClient()
    Dim msgResponseMessage As Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

    Const GODADDY_API_CALL As String = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/" & YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME_HERE & "/records/A/@"

    MyWebClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("sso-key", GODADDYKEY_AND_SECRET)
    msgResponseMessage = Await MyWebClient.GetAsync(GODADDY_API_CALL)

    If msgResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode = True Then
        objGoDaddyResult = Await msgResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    Else
        objGoDaddyResult = msgResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase
    End If

    Return objGoDaddyResult

End Function


Private Async Function PutGoDaddyARecord(ByVal strNewARecord As String) As Task(Of String)
    Dim sGoDaddyData As String
    Dim wcWebClient = New Net.Http.HttpClient()
    Dim scStringContent As Net.Http.StringContent
    Dim msgGoDaddyResponse As Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
    Dim uriMyURI As Uri

    Const GODADDY_API_CALL As String = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/" & YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME_HERE & "/records/A/@"
    Const GODADDY_DATA As String = "[{\034data\034:\034[[NEW_A_RECORD]]\034}]"
    sGoDaddyData = Replace(GODADDY_DATA, "[[NEW_A_RECORD]]", strNewARecord,,, CompareMethod.Text)
    sGoDaddyData = ghEscape(sGoDaddyData)
    uriMyURI = New Uri(GODADDY_API_CALL)
    scStringContent = New Net.Http.StringContent(sGoDaddyData, Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json")

    wcWebClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("sso-key", GODADDYKEY_AND_SECRET)
    msgGoDaddyResponse = Await wcWebClient.GetAsync(GODADDY_API_CALL)

    If msgGoDaddyResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode = True Then
        msgGoDaddyResponse = Await wcWebClient.PutAsync(uriMyURI, scStringContent)
        objGoDaddyResult = msgGoDaddyResponse.ReasonPhrase
    Else
        objGoDaddyResult = msgGoDaddyResponse.ReasonPhrase
    End If

    Return objGoDaddyResult

End Function

'
' Calls three websites
' This is more a robust approach because it scrapes somebody else's website and we have no control over their future changes.
'
Private Function GetExternalIPMain() As String
    Dim sReturn As String = DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS

    sReturn = GetExternalIP1()
    If sReturn = DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS Then
        sReturn = GetExternalIP2()
        If sReturn = DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS Then
            sReturn = GetExternalIP3()
            If sReturn = DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS Then
                'Console.ReadKey()
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return Trim(sReturn)
End Function


' [1 of 3] feron.it
Private Function GetExternalIP1() As String
    Const WEB_PAGE_WITH_MYIP As String = "http://tools.feron.it/php/ip.php"
    Dim sReturn As String = DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS
    Dim MyWebClient As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient()

    Try
        sReturn = MyWebClient.DownloadString(WEB_PAGE_WITH_MYIP)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return sReturn
End Function

' [2 of 3] dyndns.org
Private Function GetExternalIP2() As String
    Const WEB_PAGE_WITH_MYIP As String = "http://checkip.dyndns.org/"
    Const BEGIN_SCRAPE_STRING As String = "Current IP Address: "
    Const END_SCRAPE_STRING As String = "</body>"

    Dim sReturn As String = DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS
    Dim MyWebClient As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient()
    Dim sPageContents As String = ""

    Try
        sPageContents = MyWebClient.DownloadString(WEB_PAGE_WITH_MYIP)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If Len(sPageContents) > 0 Then
        sReturn = ghExtract(sPageContents, BEGIN_SCRAPE_STRING, END_SCRAPE_STRING)
    End If

    Return sReturn
End Function

' [3 of 3] ap-adress.com
Private Function GetExternalIP3() As String
    Const WEB_PAGE_WITH_MYIP As String = "http://www.ip-adress.com/"
    Const BEGIN_SCRAPE_STRING As String = "Your IP address is: <strong>"
    Const END_SCRAPE_STRING As String = "</strong>"

    Dim sReturn As String = DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS
    Dim MyWebClient As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient()
    Dim sPageContents As String = ""

    Try
        sPageContents = MyWebClient.DownloadString(WEB_PAGE_WITH_MYIP)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If Len(sPageContents) > 0 Then
        sReturn = ghExtract(sPageContents, BEGIN_SCRAPE_STRING, END_SCRAPE_STRING)
    End If

    Return sReturn
End Function

' Function I like
Private Function ghExtract(ByVal strString As String, ByVal strBegin As String, ByVal strEnd As String) As String
    Dim sReturn As String = ""

    Dim iTempBegin As Integer = InStr(strString, strBegin, CompareMethod.Text) + Len(strBegin)
    Dim iTempEnd As Integer = InStr(strString, strEnd, CompareMethod.Text)
    If iTempEnd > iTempBegin Then
        sReturn = Strings.Mid(strString, iTempBegin, iTempEnd - iTempBegin)
    End If

    Return sReturn

End Function

' Function I like
Public Function ghEscape(ByVal strString As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    If ghInstrBinary(strString, vbWhack) = True Then
        For i = 1 To 254
            strString = Replace(strString, vbWhack & Strings.Right("00" & i.ToString, 3), Chr(i),,, CompareMethod.Binary)
        Next
    End If
    Return strString
End Function

' Function I like
Function ghInstrBinary(ByVal strString As String, strSearchString As String) As Boolean
    Dim bReturn As Boolean = False
    If InStr(strString, strSearchString, CompareMethod.Binary) > 0 Then
        bReturn = True
    End If
    Return bReturn
End Function
```

End Module